# Dice repeat need assistance

Tags: python

Hi i have done this random dice game and need help creating a loop that will let me when the user enters a invalid number I would like them to try again. Here is my code please help!

```
import random
dice = int(input("What sided dice do you want to use? (e.g. 4, 6 or 12): "))
if dice == 4:
                random_number = int(random.randrange(1,4))
                print ("You selected a 4 sided dice")
                print ("Your dice has rolled ")
                print (random_number)
elif dice == 6:
                random_number2 = int(random.randrange(1,6))
                print ("You selected a 6 sided dice")
                print("Your dice has rolled ")
                print (random_number2)
elif dice == 12:
                random_number3 = int(random.randrange(1,12))
                print ("You selected a 12 sided dice")
                print("Your dice has rolled  ")
                print (random_number3)
else:
                print(("You didn't select a valid sided dice, try again!"))*
```

Comment: Note that `random.randrange` doesn't include the endpoint, so `randrange(1,4)` will give you any of `[1, 2, 3]` only.

Comment: There is *a lot* of duplication in this code; you can use the `dice` variable to cut out about two thirds of it (e.g. `random.randrange(1, dice+1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
import random
dice = None
while dice not in (4, 6, 12):
    dice = int(input("What sided dice do you want to use? (e.g. 4, 6 or 12): ")
if dice == 4:
            random_number = int(random.randrange(1,4))
            print ("You selected a 4 sided dice")
            print ("Your dice has rolled ")
            print (random_number)
elif dice == 6:
            random_number2 = int(random.randrange(1,6))
            print ("You selected a 6 sided dice")
            print("Your dice has rolled ")
            print (random_number2)

elif dice == 12:
            random_number3 = int(random.randrange(1,12))
            print ("You selected a 12 sided dice")
            print("Your dice has rolled  ")
            print (random_number3)
```

Comment: I recommend using one short loop that prompts until it gets a valid response and then switching based on the input. This is much more error-prone; if any of the cases is missing a `break`, it has a bug.

Comment: Now you have a `NameError`; you need to define `dice`, as per my answer

Comment: Depends on who and where are you. Not too sure if i'm interested.

Answer (score 3):

You need two things for this:

1. A `while` loop, to keep going around until you get what you want; and
2. A collection of acceptable answers to check against.

For example, one simple solution would be to wrap your current `input` statement with:

```
dice = 0
while dice not in (4, 6, 12):
    dice = ...
# continue
```